# How to access terraform provider attributes within resources in terraform script?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a basic terraform script to spin up an ec2 on aws. For time being. I'm using `local-exec` provisioner. The script looks like this.

```
    provider "aws" {
      profile = "default"
      region  = "eu-central-1"
      version = "2.53"
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "gsb_ec2" {
      ami           = "ami-0b418580298265d5c"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"

      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "echo ${aws_instance.gsb_ec2.public_ip} > ip_address.txt"

      }
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "echo ${aws_instance.gsb_ec2.public_ip} > ip_address.txt"
          }
    }
```

I want to echo `provider region` just like I'm echoing aws instance public ip.

I'm getting following error because provider is not a resource obviously.

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource
```

So, how do I access provider attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a data component to [get to the current region](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/region.html):

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}
```

Then you can echo `data.aws_region.current.name`